# jQueryFade Out On Page Reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, fadein, fadeout

I wonder whether someone can help me please.

The extract of script below enables a user to delete records from a table, linked to a mySQL database.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('form.delete').submit(function(e){ 

            e.preventDefault();
            var elem = $(this).closest('.delete');
            var lid = $(this).serialize();
            $.confirm({
                 'title'    : 'Delete Confirmation',
            'message'   : 'If you delete this Location, all associated Find records will also be deleted. <br /><br />They cannot be restored at a later time! Do you wish to continue?',
                'buttons'   : {
                    'Yes'   : {
                'class' : 'blue',
                'action': function(){
                //elem.slideUp();
                              $.ajax({ 
                            url: 'deletelocation.php', 
                            type: 'POST', 
                            data: lid, 
                            success: function(response) { 
                            console.log('success', response); 
                                    setTimeout(function() { 
                                    $('body').fadeOut(400, function(){
                                    location.reload();
                                    setTimeout(function(){
                                    $('body').fadeIn(400);
                                     }, 500);
                                     window.scrollTo(x-coord, y-coord);
                                 });
                            }, 2000);
                            }, 
                            error: function() { 
                            console.log('error') 
                            } 
                            }); 
                    }
                },
                'No'    : {
                    'class' : 'gray',
                                        'action': function(){}  // Nothing to do in this case. You can as well omit the action property.

                }
            }
        });

    });

    })
</script>
```

I can manage to get the 'Delete Confirmation' message working and the actual deletion of the record, but I'm having a little difficulty in adding a 'Fade out' as the deletion takes place and then a 'Fade in' upon page reload.

I've read a number of posts and from these I came up with the following which I've integrated into the above :

```
setTimeout(function() { 
$('body').fadeOut(400, function(){
location.reload();
setTimeout(function(){
$('body').fadeIn(400);
}, 500);
window.scrollTo(x-coord, y-coord);
});
}, 2000);
```

However this doesn't work, and I'm not sure why. I just wondered where someone may be able to take a look at this please and let me know where I'm going wrong.

Many thanks and kind regards

Comment: Rather than fading the whole page, can you just remove and fade out the record from the DOM? This also saves the user a complete refresh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

firstly thank you very much for your help. I have however realised where my problem lay. I had the JavaScript after the `body` section of my page. I've now moved this to the beginning of my script before the form, and it works fine. Kind regards

Answer (score 1):

The script after location.reload() does not executed because the page is reload.

You can add a flag in your url (#reload) and at start of page's load, you can do 
$('body').hide().fadeIn() if you find the flag.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have a javascript action set to occur after the location.reload().

location.reload() will reload the page, and anything left in the JS stack at the time the page reloaded will be lost.

You would need to add the body fadeIn as a function to the page itself, perhaps if there is a particular url param? So rather than reloading the page, you would be navigating to the same page, plus a specified querystring, such as ?reload=true, or to a specific anchor, such as #myAnchor